# Sourcetree Git Is the repository it's own folder or is it the project folder?

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm new to git and Sourcetree. I want a simple local repository.

Is the repository it's own folder or is it the project folder?

Answer (score 0):

You first go to your folder using `cd "Your folder name"`
then initialize a repository using `git init`. You can add any file and commit it. This is how you have to use git and local repository. I will suggest you to read more about [git](https://git-scm.com/) and [version control](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control) and then try this on your system. If you face any problems then ask here with full details.